# Auto-fill required form field if left blank

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, forms

Is it possible to have a required form field be automatically filled with a particular string upon form submission if, and only if, it had been left blank by the user?  If so, how?

Ideally, I would like to do this with minimal code, and I'm working with PHP, HTML, and CSS.

---

I added the javascript tag because I'm guessing that js will be necessary to "force" submission of a form with a required field left empty.

Comment: Why down vote without commenting as to what makes this a poor question?

Comment: I imagine it's because `This question does not show any research effort`, as the tooltip for the downvote button clearly states

Comment: If your research efforts yield a result, please share. I looked and failed to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This updates the $_POST value but not the form

```
if (empty($_POST['name_of_item'])) {
    $_POST['name_of_item'] = 'default value';    
}
```

Comment: So, in this case, the field in question will never appear filled. (As far as the user knows, it was submitted blank.)  However, the POST data will contain a value that I can save in the database?

Comment: I don;t think I need to combine it with your other answer.  If the answer to my question immediately above your comment is "Yes," then you've successfully answered my question.

Comment: BTW if (empty($_POST['name_of_item'])) doesn't work properly try (!isset($_POST['name_of_item'])) or ($_POST['name_of_item'] != "")

Comment: One issue though. Upon hitting the submit button, won't the user receive a message from the browser informing them to fill in the required field, because of the `required` attribute.  In other words, the form data won't be submitted to be processed by the PHP code.  Right?

Comment: Your PHP code works--I've tested it--but it doesn't overcome the `required` attribute.  That's the first step.  Maybe that deserves its own question: "How to force submission of a form with an unfilled required field?"

Comment: BTW about the "required" attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp it is a HTML5 field that apparently isn't supported in Internet Explorer and Safari....

Answer (score 0):

This should update the form but not the $_POST value

```
<?php
    $default_value = isset($_POST) && empty($_POST['item_name']) ? 'added_value' : $_POST['item_name'];
?>

<input type="text" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $default_value;?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this html classical technique 
`<input type="text" value="DefaultValueThatUserWIllSee" />` this will ensure that if user skips it, you'll get the default value...:)

Comment: This won't actually do what I'm asking for.  I want to know that the field was empty when the submit button was hit.  Thanks though.